# How can i add a QueryHint to a Hibernate Custom Query?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, query-hints

I'm trying to add the Oracle Query Hint `/*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS PARALLEL(16) */` to my Custom Query which looks similar to this:

```java
@Query("SELECT " +
      " FROM myTable tab " +
      " WHERE tab.create_date >= to_date(:dateFrom) " +
      " AND tab.create_date < to_date(:dateTo)")
List<MyModel> findEntriesByDate( @Param("dateFrom") String dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") String dateTo);
```

I cannot find any way to make this work. I tried various things, for example adding this on top of the method:

```java
@QueryHints({
            @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.COMMENT, value = "GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS")
    })
```

or

```java
@QueryHints({
            @QueryHint(name = GATHER_PLAN_STATISTIC, value = "GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS")
    })
```

Is there a way to make this work or do I have to change my approach?

Comment: @BobJarvis sorry, that was a mistake while coppying.

Comment: De nada. Is there a reason you can't put the hint-comment into the SQL, as it looks like you're passing a complete query anyways?

Comment: Spring Boot throws an exception if I include the hint-comment in the sql..